# How can I set the my.ini location at install time

Tags: mysql, installation

I have an application with a NSIS installer, it installs my application and also mysql 5.7.25.

When installing it create a my.ini inside :

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7
```

The problem is that one of my client has another application which run with mysql 5.7.20. which also has a my.ini in the same place. So my installer overwrite the existing file and break the other app.

**When installing how can I tell the installer where the my.ini is ?**
My idea is to put it inside my application folder and tell mysql to look here:

```
C:\ProgramData\MyAPP
```

I am installing mysql like that (in 2 steps):

I install the installer :

> "msiexec" /quiet /norestart /i
> "C:\MYAPP\Mysql\mysql-installer-community-5.7.25.0.msi"
> INSTALLDIR="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7"

then mysql

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Installer for
> Windows\MySQLInstallerConsole.exe" community install -silent
> server;5.7.25;x64:*:port=3306;passwd=root;installdir="C:\Program
> Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7"

Thanks

Comment: Please use the last version of mysql 5.7.32 or even better the newest versopn 8,. it has a lot of mprovements.

Comment: Also you can tell the installer to copy files to other directtories, as you have admin rights

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution :
I believed that mysql installation was creating the service. But I was wrong the windows service is created later in my installer :

```
'"$1\bin\mysqld.exe" --install ${MYSQL_SERVICE_64}'
```

So can add the argument "--defaults-file" here and place the .ini where ever I want.